# Toggle between two function loops on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I've set have two sets of two functions that animate an SVG, one set in a vertical loop (Rightscale.verticalUp and Rightscale.verticalDown) and one is a horizontal loop (Rightscale.horizontalUp or Rightscale.horizontalDown). Clicking the SVG should alternate between each loop - stopping one loop and starting the other infinitely. How can I go about doing this? I would guess that somehow I need to find out what function has just been called, kill it and call a function from the alternate loop?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```js
var Rightscale = {
    identifier: 0,
    svgEl: $('#right').find('svg'),
    svgH: $('#right').find('.scale').height(),
    svgW: $('#right').find('.scale').width(),
    cntH: $('#right').height(),
    cntW: $('#right').width(),

    init: function() {
        Rightscale.svgEl.on("click", function() {
            if(Rightscale.svgEl == 0 || 3 || 4) {
                // Here I want to stop Rightscale.horizontalUp or Rightscale.horizontalDown if it is running but how?
                Rightscale.verticalUp(Rightscale.svgEl)
            } else if(Rightscale.svgEl == 1 || 2) {
                // Here I want to stop Rightscale.verticalUp or Rightscale.verticalDown if it is running, how can I do this?
                Rightscale.horizontalWide(Rightscale.svgEl)
            }
        });
    },
    verticalUp: function($elt) {
        var scaleH = Rightscale.cntH / Rightscale.svgH;
        Rightscale.identifier = 1
        $elt.css('transform', 'scaleY(' + scaleH + ')')
        var verticalUpTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            Rightscale.verticalDown($elt);
        }, 5000);
        console.log(Rightscale.identifier)
    },
    verticalDown: function($elt) {
        Rightscale.identifier = 2
        $elt.css('transform', 'scaleY(1)')
        var verticalDownTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            Rightscale.verticalUp($elt);
        }, 5000);
        console.log(Rightscale.identifier)
    },
    horizontalWide: function($elt) {
        Rightscale.identifier = 3
        var scaleW = Rightscale.cntW / Rightscale.svgW;
        $elt.css('transform', 'scaleX(' + scaleW + ')')
        var horizontalWideTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            Rightscale.horizontalSmall($elt);
        }, 5000);
        console.log(Rightscale.identifier)
    },
    horizontalSmall: function($elt) {
        Rightscale.identifier = 4
        $elt.css('transform', 'scaleX(1)')
        var horizontalSmallTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            Rightscale.horizontalWide($elt);
        }, 5000);
        console.log(Rightscale.identifier)
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    Rightscale.init();
});
```

```css
#right {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.scale {
    font-size: 0px;
    width: 20%;
}
svg {
    transition: transform 5000ms linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="right">
<div class="scale">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         style="enable-background:new 0 0 0 100;" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
        <path d="M81.2,117.5c-6.6,8.8-17.5,13-34.8,13c-17.7,0-28.6-4.3-35.2-13.9c-5.3-7.5-7.7-17.1-8.5-32.4c-0.2-4.3-0.4-9.8-0.4-16.6
            c0-18.4,0.9-27.3,3.6-37.3C7.2,25.5,9.2,21,11.7,17C18.5,6.7,29,2,45.6,2c17.3,0,27.9,3.8,34.6,12.4c7.9,10.2,10.4,22,10.4,51.2
            C90.6,93.4,87.9,108.1,81.2,117.5z M57.4,66.1l-0.2-16.4C56.9,24,56.1,21.9,46.9,21.9c-6.2,0-9.4,3.4-10.2,10.9
            c-0.6,7.5-0.9,21.8-0.9,38.4c0,13,0.2,25,0.8,29.4c0.8,6.2,4.1,9.4,10,9.4c5.6,0,9-3.2,9.8-9.6c0.6-4.5,1.1-19.2,1.1-31.1V66.1z"/>
</g>
    </svg>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would add a bool variable in one of your functions that gets set to true or false  upon clicking where you want to click. Inside the other function you want to run, you can write an if statement that if(yourbool == true){ //execute  your code}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
if(Rightscale.svgEl == 0 || 3 || 4) {
```

change that line with:

```
if([0, 3, 4].indexOf(Rightscale.identifier)>-1) {
```

Your test condition returns true if **Rightscale.svgEl** is 0 else **3**: in any case it's always true.

Moreover, clear the timeout if the new click happens in less the timeout delay:

A last aspect to take in consideration is the transition end event: for this you may take a look to [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend).

```js
var Rightscale = {
    identifier: 0,
    svgEl: $('#right').find('svg'),
    svgH: $('#right').find('.scale').height(),
    svgW: $('#right').find('.scale').width(),
    cntH: $('#right').height(),
    cntW: $('#right').width(),
    timerId: -1,

    init: function() {
        Rightscale.svgEl.on("click", function(e) {
            clearTimeout(Rightscale.timerId);
            if([0, 3, 4].indexOf(Rightscale.identifier)>-1) {
                // Here I want to stop Rightscale.horizontalUp or Rightscale.horizontalDown if it is running but how?
                Rightscale.verticalUp(Rightscale.svgEl)
            } else if ([1, 2].indexOf(Rightscale.identifier)>-1) {
                // Here I want to stop Rightscale.verticalUp or Rightscale.verticalDown if it is running, how can I do this?
                Rightscale.horizontalWide(Rightscale.svgEl)
            }
        });
    },
    verticalUp: function($elt) {
        var scaleH = Rightscale.cntH / Rightscale.svgH;
        Rightscale.identifier = 1
        $elt.css('transform', 'scaleY(' + scaleH + ')')
        Rightscale.timerId = setTimeout(function(){
            Rightscale.verticalDown($elt);
        }, 5000);
        //console.log(Rightscale.identifier)
    },
    verticalDown: function($elt) {
        Rightscale.identifier = 2
        $elt.css('transform', 'scaleY(1)')
        Rightscale.timerId = setTimeout(function(){
            Rightscale.verticalUp($elt);
        }, 5000);
        //console.log(Rightscale.identifier)
    },
    horizontalWide: function($elt) {
        Rightscale.identifier = 3
        var scaleW = Rightscale.cntW / Rightscale.svgW;
        $elt.css('transform', 'scaleX(' + scaleW + ')')
        Rightscale.timerId = setTimeout(function(){
            Rightscale.horizontalSmall($elt);
        }, 5000);
        //console.log(Rightscale.identifier)
    },
    horizontalSmall: function($elt) {
        Rightscale.identifier = 4
        $elt.css('transform', 'scaleX(1)')
        Rightscale.timerId = setTimeout(function(){
            Rightscale.horizontalWide($elt);
        }, 5000);
        //console.log(Rightscale.identifier)
    }
}

Rightscale.init();
```

```css
#right {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.scale {
    font-size: 0px;
    width: 20%;
}

svg {
    transition: transform 5000ms linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="right">
    <div class="scale">
        <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         style="enable-background:new 0 0 0 100;" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
        <path d="M81.2,117.5c-6.6,8.8-17.5,13-34.8,13c-17.7,0-28.6-4.3-35.2-13.9c-5.3-7.5-7.7-17.1-8.5-32.4c-0.2-4.3-0.4-9.8-0.4-16.6
            c0-18.4,0.9-27.3,3.6-37.3C7.2,25.5,9.2,21,11.7,17C18.5,6.7,29,2,45.6,2c17.3,0,27.9,3.8,34.6,12.4c7.9,10.2,10.4,22,10.4,51.2
            C90.6,93.4,87.9,108.1,81.2,117.5z M57.4,66.1l-0.2-16.4C56.9,24,56.1,21.9,46.9,21.9c-6.2,0-9.4,3.4-10.2,10.9
            c-0.6,7.5-0.9,21.8-0.9,38.4c0,13,0.2,25,0.8,29.4c0.8,6.2,4.1,9.4,10,9.4c5.6,0,9-3.2,9.8-9.6c0.6-4.5,1.1-19.2,1.1-31.1V66.1z"/>
</g>
    </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply @gaetanoM, this works great, I really appreciate the explanation